# Strange language codes in Accept-Language header

Tags: php, http, localization, http-headers

I'm detecting user accepted languages through `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` and I'm getting strange language and country codes.

Language codes I've found:

- `es-419`
- `es-es_tradnl`
- `*`

I've checked some code language listings and haven't found these codes:

- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp
- http://www.metamodpro.com/browser-language-codes

I understand that es-es_tradnl means Spanish traditional, but any clue about es-419 nor '*'...
Any clues about where does that codes come from?

**Edit, question extended:**
Where can I find a full list of language codes?

Comment: `es-419` stands for Latin American Spanish.

Comment: where can I find that description?

Comment: yah, that was obvious...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HTTPbis, Part 3, Section 2.4](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p3-payload-17.html#rfc.section.2.4)_

> The name space of language subtags is administered by the IANA (see http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry).

Comment: I cannot see es-es_tradnl on that list

Comment: The IANA list, per definition, is the complete list of *registered* language codes. Of course that doesn't help when the code isn't registered, in which case Google is your friend.

Comment: Your comment completes your answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

[HTTP/1.1: Header Field Definitions:](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

> The special range "*", if present in the Accept-Language field,
>   matches every tag not matched by any other range present in the
>   Accept-Language field.

---

As I already mentioned in the comments, `es-419` stands for

> Spanish appropriate for the Latin America and Caribbean region, using
>   the UN region code

from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_code)

Comment: Should I interpret then that users with a * as accept language accept any language?

Comment: @clinisbut If the language quality factor assigned to it is greater than zero, then yes (so it has no `;q=0` after it).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I would like to point you directly at the resource. If you go here (link below) you will find both those cryptic looking language codes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233968.aspx

I hope this helps, since the others did not have the link handy for you, I thought I would add it. There is a list of 449 language codes (which is just a language code and country/region code combined).

That list is updated a few times a year, check the parent page of the listing I gave you if you want to see the update history. Hope this helps.